# How can I re-populate a list in a <div> after adding an item to it using AJAX?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Specifically, I have a number of pages in my Rails app that use the same partial.  In the action handler for each page I create an array object (e.g. `@list_elements`) based on a database query.  Each page uses a different query so that each page has different list elements in it.  At the top of each page I have a `form_remote_tag` containing an edit field, allowing the user to add a new element in a dynamic, AJAXy fashion (think something like Twitter 'What's happening' box).

My problem is that when the AJAX command fires I need to reload the list to include the newly added item, but the contents of the list were determined by a database query.  I need to remember which query applies to the current page (i.e. controller action) so that I can run it again.  I thought about storing something in the rails `session` structure but it seems like overkill - it's like storing the current page all the time.

Anybody done anything like this and have a nice Railsy way to achieve it?

Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't you just re-render the partial in your rjs template?

`page[:div_element].replace_html :partial => 'partial'`

If you perform the query and define the array in the controller action, then an ajax call will refresh that array.

Comment: Maybe I could - not used RJS at all yet though so no idea!  I'll look into that.

Comment: If you're using AJAX in Rails, you need to be using rjs. Rjs makes AJAX soooo easy. It's wonderful.